# Tycho missing plugin when building an update site

Tags: maven, tycho, eclipse-pde

When I build my project by tycho-maven-plugin, I encounter the following message:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: foo-updatesite raw:0.2.0.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):0.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR]   Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: foo-feature.feature.group 0.2.0.qualifier requires 'foo-plugin 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: foo-updatesite raw:0.2.0.'SNAPSHOT'/format(n[.n=0;[.n=0;[-S]]]):0.2.0-SNAPSHOT depends on: foo-feature.feature.group [0.2.0,0.2.1)
```

This error occurs when building an update site. Plugin and feature are build normally. I build the update site from PDE without issues.

The project structure is common: there is a parent project with `pom` packaging and three modules: plugin, feature and updatesite. Of course, I invoke `mvn clean package` from the parent project.

What can be the reason for this error? How can I debug it?

**UPD**: I tried many things: removed "grandparent" pom, removed SNAPSHOT/qualifier, played with configuration. However, I found the solution: I switched to tycho 0.19 instead of 0.21. So I suppose there is a bug in tycho 0.21.

Comment: What happens if you build the plugin project alone? I suppose that there is an inconsistency between artifactId and Bundle-SymbolicName in that project.

Comment: The plugin is built without issues. I checked MANIFEST.MF and pom.xml. `artifactId` and `Bundle-SymbolicName` are identical.

Comment: Is the bundle platform-specific, i.e. does it have a Eclipse-PlatformFilter header?

Comment: If you think that there is a bug in Tycho, you should report it [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho). Make sure that you attach a small example project which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error message

```
Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0
```

indicates that you have defined an environment filter when you include the plugin `foo-plugin` in the `feature.xml`. However this does not explain the dependency resolution error you are seeing. The only way I can reproduce the error message is by adding an `Eclipse-PlatformFilter` header in the manifest of the plugin using a value which doesn't match environments configuration in the POM.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message:

```
Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: foo-feature.feature.group 0.2.0.qualifier requires 'foo-plugin 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

For some reason this error (also) means, that `foo-plugin` is present... twice.

So in your case, open the "Content" tab of the "Target Editor" and make sure that `foo-plugin` is not present in two distinct versions. I common way this could happen is if two features contain the same bundle.