# Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I've the following error while building an RCP app with Maven Tycho:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve target definition:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group     1.6.900.v20210227-0235
[ERROR]   Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.6.900.v20210227-0235 requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.equinox.security.macosx [1.101.300.v20210212-1601,1.101.300.v20210212-1601]' but it could not be found
```

This questions seems similar to [Tycho missing plugin when building an update site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975870/tycho-missing-plugin-when-building-an-update-site), but the solution there doesn't work. If I unselect the double packages in target the error remains.

I've tried to build an ARM package on an Intel Mac. Here's the pom snippet:

```
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>aarch64</arch>
                        </environment>
```

Or is this not possible at all?

Any hints are welcome.

Regards,
Ralf.

Comment: Only the current 4.20M3 milestone has macOS aarch64 support - are you using that?

Comment: No, I'm using 4.19 (2021-03). I've just tried the latest milestone, but I couldn't compile the project with it (stops without any error message after a few seconds). I'll wait for the final release.
Only one question for the moment: Is it possible to compile an ARM product on an Intel machine?
Thanks,
Ralf.

Comment: I don't know for sure but since the build is essentially just assembling already built plug-ins there should not be a problem - same as building for Linux or Windows on a Mac.

Comment: Any updates on this? Where can I set the 4.20M3 milestone? Milestone of what?